# how to toggle class of <li> onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Onchanging the dropdown, i want to **change the class of  < li> class by using li ID**

**HTML code :**

```
 <select id="table_no" name="table_no">
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
              ...
              ...
    </select>

     <ul id=place">
         <li id="1" class="seat selectedSeat"></li>
         <li id="2" class="seat selectedSeat"></li>
         ....
         ....
     </ul>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
 $("#table_no").change(function (){
 var table_no = $(this).val() 
 $("#".table_no).removeClass('selectedSeat');
 $("#".table_no).addClass('pinkclass');
 });
```

IN THIS CODE I WANT TO REMOVE **selectedSeat** CLASS , add **pinkclass**  , when the dropdopdown change. in this code the li class is not changing ..

Comment: `id` should not start with a numeric character - it should always be an alphabetic character. (so `id="1"` is invalid)

Comment: @freefaller It's valid as of HTML5, but may cause problems in older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `+` symbol for concatenation, this is not `PHP`,

```
$("#table_no").change(function (){
 var table_no = $(this).val() 
 $("#" + table_no).removeClass('selectedSeat');
 $("#" + table_no).addClass('pinkclass');
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z68SF/6/)**

Comment: @milind Thanks for making the demo..!